# Force menu inflating behaviour outside the action bar

Tags: android, menu, android-inflate

I'm currently developing an `android` application, whose target is `API19` (min sdk version is set to `API14`). This app **will not run in a mobile phone**, but on a custom device.

The screen is **not a touch screen**, so user interaction will rely on a keyboard, and also I have to mention that this app **won't have action bar implemented** (I'm currently hidding it).

I'm trying to implement the old style menu behaviour, where you could bring up the menu by pressing the `menu` button on your device (deprecated since `API10`), like this:

[image: old menu behaviour]

So, things get complicated when I try to inflate the menu, as `android` will  automatically inflate my menu in the action bar (since `API11`):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

---

**QUESTION:**

**I know it's deprecated**, but still I want to implement the menu that way, therefore, **is there any way I can force android to inflate this menu "the old way", without lowering my target API ?**

Comment: You've to go back to Gingerbread

Comment: Sadly that's what I'm afraid of, I hope somebody comes with any workaround or so, but I think I'll be forced back to Gingerbread :(

Comment: It's possible to do that with this library if you can sit and have it tweaked [link] https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel I did something similar with that library recently

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep an eye on that library, I hope it doesn't take a large amount of time to modify it as my screen can't capture touch events :P

Comment: I know. I can write a code to do that, but not for the next 8/9hrs. That's why I said, you can download the library and check the SlidingUpPanelLayout class and inspect the Panel stated

Comment: Oh, I don't want to waste your time, but I appreciate your offer, very kind of you, so dont worry :). Right now I'm thinking of building my own menu behaviour, I mean, having my menu buttons hidden until user presses `menu` button, then show them. As I don't have more than 3 menu items, I think this will work best, and therefore I won't have to fall back 9 `API` levels to archieve this desired behaviour...